# Docker not connecting to port

Tags: docker

When I run the command:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:3100 username/sb-dockerized
```

and go to localhost:8080, it doesn't connect. Says "This page isn't working"

In my Dockerfile I am exposing port 3100

```
EXPOSE 3100
```

Logs

```
2021-07-10 15:53:27.828  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.e.s.SpringBootDockerizedApplication    : Starting SpringBootDockerizedApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 15.0.1 on d3b451475e8d with PID 1 (/clancinio/lib/sb-dockerized.jar started by root in /clancinio/lib)
2021-07-10 15:53:27.832  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.e.s.SpringBootDockerizedApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-07-10 15:53:29.556  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-07-10 15:53:29.579  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-07-10 15:53:29.579  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.48]
2021-07-10 15:53:29.679  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-07-10 15:53:29.679  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1755 ms
2021-07-10 15:53:30.300  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-07-10 15:53:30.316  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.e.s.SpringBootDockerizedApplication    : Started SpringBootDockerizedApplication in 3.173 seconds (JVM running for 3.872)
```

Any idea of what could be going wrong?

Comment: you started service on port 8080 which is running inside the container. Your mapping will be -p 3100:8080

Comment: I think it’s correct. He has exposed 3100 inside container and publishing it on port 8080 of host. `-p hostPort:containerPort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Dockerfile, `EXPOSE 8080` because your spring-boot app is listening to that port inside your container. While running, run with `docker run -d -p <<the port you want to hit in the url>>:8080 username/sb-dockerized` and then access `http://localhost:<<the port you want to hit in the url>>`

Answer (score 0):

From your browser navigate to `http://<hostIP>:8080`